# Multiple Google Plus pages for one Google Account

Tags: google-plus, google-account

Is it possible to create multiple Google+ pages (also fanpages for organizations), that are bind to one single Google account?

The background of this question is following case: I have (1) a private acount on Google and a private Google+ page. Now I'd like to create two futher pages on the same Google account: (2) a "Product or Brand" fanpage (3) and a "Company, Institution or Organization" fanpage.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just try it?

Yes, you can be the owner of multiple Google+ Pages. I myself have two (and had a third).

If there is a limit to the number you can have I don't know what it is.